# Tesseract only working with sudo

Tags: linux, ocr, tesseract, sudo

I installed tesseract ocr on my raspberry pi via `sudo apt install tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng tesseract-ocr-deu`. When i run tesseract with `sudo tesseract ...`, it's working fine, but when in don't use sudo to run tesseract, it says Error during processing. I changed the permissions on the .tif file and for the .traineddata filed to 777, so this can't be the problem. Thanks for any help!
Edit: I'm using tesseract 3.04.01
That's everything from the console:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/fax $ tesseract fax.tif fax -l deu
>   Tesseract
>   Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica
>   Error during
>   processing.

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to tell you what's wrong. What does it say besides "Error during processing"?

Comment: Nothing, that's my problem... `Error during processing` is the only output i get.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a new directory where you've never used `sudo`? Sometimes programs create and reuse log files, config files or intermediate files. In those cases, running with `sudo` first will cause those files to be owned by root, and any future run without `sudo` will fail.

Comment: I didn't run it with sudo at first. Changing the directory didn't help.

Comment: What about directory where .traineddata is located? Is it also 777?